# dl/win32 loaderror

Tags: ruby, windows

I found this script that gives you the username in Windows, but I get the following error, this is not about the username but about the missing lib, I need the lib `dl/win32` also for a couple other scripts. How to fix this?

> C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/win32 (LoadError)

```
require 'dl/win32'

def get_user_name
  api = Win32API.new(
    'advapi32.dll',
    'GetUserName',
    'PP',
    'i'
  )

  buf = "\0" * 512
  len = [512].pack('L')
  api.call(buf,len)

  buf[0..(len.unpack('L')[0])]
end

puts get_user_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what "dl/win32" is.  I have used the Win32API gem.  Using it instead of dl/win32 made your script work for me:

```
require 'Win32API'
```

Comment: that's it ! dl/win32 must be an older version of it i presume, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is you have to run

```
gem install dl
```

Comment: i did this, it installed without errors but this gem apparently has nothing to do with it because i still get the same error. dl-win32, dl/win32 or dl_win32 aren't found as gems